# How can I localize cultureinfo.DisplayName?

Tags: c#, localization, cultureinfo

I wanna get the `DisplayName` of a culturinfo with the language of `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`.

example)

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture : English

en-US => English

zh-CN => Chinese

ja-JP => Japanese

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture : Chinese

en-US => 英语 (English written in Chinese)

zh-CN => 中文 (Chinese written in Chinese)

ja-JP => 日语 (Japanese written in Chinese)
```

Comment: Why is this required ? Generally the currentCulture property is used internally by the application.  If you want to display the currentCulture on UI, then you can localize it like any other string.

Comment: Sorry, that's not supported (you can't get, say, *Greenlandic* `kl-GL` in *Telugu* `te-IN`); all you can get is either
*English* name of any culture - `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.EnglishName`; or *native* name of culture itself (Russian in Russian, German in German etc.) - `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NativeName`.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.